# com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.UnsupportedSignatureMethodException: HMAC-SHA1 Being thrown in Eclipse v2022-03 but not in Eclipse v2019-09

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having an issue with a Java Application that connects to Smugmug via their API.
I wrote the application in 2019, using Eclipse 2019-09, and it works fine. I upgraded Eclipse to 03-22 and imported the code to that environment. The projects are configured identically in both versions of eclipse, same code, same  JRE (1.80_231), same compliance level, 1.8, same libraries. However when I run the app in the later version, I get this exception:

com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.UnsupportedSignatureMethodException: HMAC-SHA1

This simply does happen when running in the earlier Eclipse.

The only clue I have been able to find is a  response to a 2014 query from Sun:

"Jersey 1.x supports HMAC_SHA1 for OAuth 1. This exception occurs if the class with name "HMAC_SHA1” cannot be found using META-INF/services lookup. Do you have the jar "oauth-signature-*.jar” on the classpath? Which jersey version do you use?"

I do have the oauth-signature jar in the classpath in both the newer and older Eclipse environments (1.19.4).

So I am thinking I am missing something in the way Eclipse 03-22 is handling this, but the project in that version is showing me no errors prior to run time.

If anyone can direct me to where I should look, would much appreciate it.

Command line created by Eclipse 9-19

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/SmugmugClient/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/Smugmug/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/activation.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-net-3.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/fontbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/google-api-spelling-java-1.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/hunspell.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/itext-2.0.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jama.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxb-impl-2.1.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jcommon-1.0.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmpbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/saxon-he-9.3.0.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/sqljdbc4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/suggester-1.1.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xercesImpl.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/preflight-app-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/preflight-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-excelant-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-examples-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/pdfbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/ostermillerutils-1.08.02.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/ojdbc6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mail.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-queryparser-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-queries-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-core-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/libphonenumber-7.2.8.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jxl.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jsoup-1.8.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/junit-4.3.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jna.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreesvg-2.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jempbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jdom.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/gt-referencing-2.5.7.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/metadata-extractor-2.12.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmpcore-6.0.6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-client-1.19.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/oauth-client-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/oauth-signature-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-core-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-bundle-1.8-ea03.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/client-combined-3.141.59.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/okio-1.14.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/okhttp-3.11.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/guava-25.0-jre.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/XmlCommon/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-ant.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-ha.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-tribes.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/el-api.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/jasper-el.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/servlet-api.jar walthall.smugmug.FacesUpload capture.jpg
```

Command Line generated by Eclipse 3-22

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/nwalthall/Documents/JavaDevNew/SmugmugClient/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/JavaDevNew/Smugmug/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/activation.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/client-combined-3.141.59.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/commons-net-3.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/fontbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/google-api-spelling-java-1.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/gt-referencing-2.5.7.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/guava-25.0-jre.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/hunspell.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/itext-2.0.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jama.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxb-impl-2.1.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jcommon-1.0.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jdom.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jempbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-bundle-1.8-ea03.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-client-1.19.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-client.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-common.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-container-servlet.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-core-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-hk2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-media-jaxb.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-media-json-binding.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-media-sse.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jersey-server.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jfreesvg-2.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jna.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jsoup-1.8.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/junit-4.3.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/jxl.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/libphonenumber-7.2.8.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-core-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-queries-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/lucene-queryparser-5.2.1.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mail.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/metadata-extractor-2.12.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/ojdbc6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/okhttp-3.11.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/okio-1.14.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/ostermillerutils-1.08.02.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/pdfbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-examples-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-excelant-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/saxon-he-9.3.0.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/solar.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/sqljdbc4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/suggester-1.1.2.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/swtgraphics2d.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xercesImpl.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmpbox-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/xmpcore-6.0.6.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/preflight-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/preflight-app-1.8.9.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/oauth-signature-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/JavaDev/CommonLib/oauth-client-1.19.4.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/JavaDevNew/XmlCommon/bin:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/servlet-api.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-ant.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-ha.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/catalina-tribes.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/el-api.jar:/Users/nwalthall/Documents/Java/tomcatlib/jasper-el.jar walthall.smugmug.FacesUpload capture.jpg
```

In each case a SmugMug API is being called to upload a single file to a SmugMug folder. When placed in different shell files, both of these run, but with different results. The Command Line generated from Eclipse 3-19 runs and completes without error--the file is successfully uploaded. The Command Line generated from Eclipse 3-22 runs, but fails with this exception:

```
09/06/2023 09:31:11 - ERROR walthall.smugmug.FacesUpload.com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.UnsupportedSignatureMethodException: HMAC-SHA1
```

Comment: Please show the command line of both (in the launch configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that; insert both command lines into your question formatted as _Sample Code_).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the incredibly fat classpath was the problem, though I was never able to trace the actually conflict. But paring the number of classes to around six resulted in the app running consistently in all environments.